# Parent function returning a JSON object from a nested function

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to create a function that returns a JSON object that is read from a file, however, I don't know how to return the object from the `readConfig` function. I tried to create a callback function but was unable to do so. I know the function works because when I `console.log(jsonData)` from inside the `readFile.then()`, it logs the object correctly.

```
const fs = require('node:fs')

function readConfig() {
    fs.promises.readFile('./config.json', 'utf8')
        .then(content => {
            jsonData = JSON.parse(content, null, 2);
            return jsonData
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
};


// This is what I want to do able to do with the readConfig function

data = readConfig()
console.log(data.value)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

EDIT:
I tried using the promise based return that was commented but would just get promises returned back.

```
const fs = require('node:fs')

function readConfig() {
    return fs.promises.readFile('./config.json', 'utf8')
        .then(content => {
            jsonData = JSON.parse(content, null, 2);
            return jsonData
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
};

readConfig().then(v => v);
```

However this just returns back a pending promise, I want to be able to access the values of the JSON object.
What I want to be able to do is;
`readConfig().value`
and access a value from the object but can't get this to work.
I just want to be able to access multiple values from this object in a simple way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: `readConfig().then(jsonData => {/* Do whatever with the data */})` is the way. Additionally, you can use this in an `async` function style: `const processData = async () => { const jsonData = await readConfig(); ... }`